# AggregateResult from namespace Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure - to decerialize from Json

Tags: c#, json, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I work with the class from namespace Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure :

```
 public class AggregateResult
{
    public AggregateResult(object value, AggregateFunction function);    
    public AggregateResult(object value, int count, AggregateFunction function);
    public object Value { get; }
    public string Member { get; }
    public object FormattedValue { get; }
    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; }
    public string FunctionName { get; }
    public string AggregateMethodName { get; }    
    public string Format(string format);
    public override string ToString();
}
```

And I get a json-response frome a server :

**{"NewQty":{"sum":0},"TotalQty":{"sum":0}}**

I need to write a parser function to get an object of AggregateResult-type class to fill it on the serve-side and send it back to the View. 
NewAquantity is mapped as Member, Value is set with quantity, sum - AggregateMethodName

Newtonsoft.JsonJsonConvert.DeserializeObject method unfortunately can't do it. Thank youmuch for any help